# Issuing an token for user without user interaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

Using AspNet.Identity I would like to be able to issue an automatic login for given user.

Consider following:

1. Theres an event that we want to notice user about.
2. Service thats responsible for monitoring events grabs the event
3. Service authorizes on behalf of the user
4. User receives an URL to click, that will automatically log him in and show related event

I've implemented OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, so I can call for an Token and receive it, however this requires password of the user we want to authorize.

Is there built-in mechanism to have some sort of "master" key that would be able to authorize any user based only on username and generate the token?

Comment: No. OAuth requires the user to authorize the application. You can't get around that.

Answer (score 0):

[Client Credentials Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) defined in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (OAuth 2.0) issues an access token which is not associated with any user, meaning that user login is not needed.

It is okay to allow client applications having access tokens issued through Client Credentials Flow to access **public** information about a user. However, if you allowed them to access **private** information about a user (= information that should not be disclosed to any other user), it would be an obvious security problem.